# Angular 6 - Control if component is visable or not from service or other components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a component which has a spinner on it and it's placed in app.component.html

```
<app-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></app-spinner>
```

on my app.component.ts I've set isLoading to False to start with.

Then I have a service which contains to methods that like getData.

```
getData() {
    // show spinner
    this.http.get('url here');
    // Hide Spinner
}
```

My Question is... If the spinner is on app.component.html and .ts and has a variable there that shows and hide's it ... How to I change that value from other components or from the service that's living in app.component.ts, unless there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Services should not touch the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *Subject* or *BehaviorSubject* in your service and use subscribe method on the same from your component to get latest value.

service.ts file

```
isLoading = true;
public loader = new BehaviorSubject(isLoading)

getData(){
 this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(()=>{
  this.isLoading = false
  this.loader.next(this.isLoading)
})
```

.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.testService.loader.subscribe(value=>console.log(value))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the service method in your app.component.ts and set the isLoading boolean value when you *subscribe* to the response of the getData() method of the service.

```
   getDataFromService() {
    // show spinner whilst waiting for the request
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.yourServiceName.getData()
      .subscribe(res => {
        // Hide spinner when res is received
        this.isLoading = false;
        // do something with the repsonse
        console.log(res);
      });
   }
```